# Passing a pointer from VBA

Tags: vba

I tried to use a C DLL function in VBA but when it is called, Excel crashes. In VBA the function is declared like this:

```
Public Declare Function HR8_CONNECT Lib "D:xxxxx.dll" _
 (ByVal PortCom As Byte, ByVal Mode As Byte, ByVal Config As Byte, ByVal Dbg As Byte, ByVal context As String) As Byte
```

I have a problem with context parameter I think which is a pointer to an unsigned char. See next the header of C function

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) UCHAR HR8_CONNECT(UCHAR, UCHAR, UCHAR, UCHAR, UCHAR*);
```

I tried a lot of variants for passing the pointer like `byval string`, `byref byte`, etc ... but Excel is crashing every time.

Comment: HR8_CONNECT seems to be declared with the `__cdecl` calling convention. VBA only accepts `__stdcall` calling convention. You won't be able to call this function from VBA.

Comment: why not use IDL?, http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2017/04/throw-away-declare-function-with-idl.html

Comment: Hello Meaden I will try to understand what you suggested me, however I'm an HW development engineer and I just tried to make an interface to access some functions to test further ...thank you!

Comment: Hello Vincent, I understand, however I captured the traffic on COM6 and  I saw that the expected data is delivered in line 95 and 97 but something is not going well further ...the best variant which is doing that is with context parameter passed by reference, is strange because means pointer to pointer ...

Comment: PS: I cannot add a print screen with COM6 capture ...

Comment: __stdcall is only used in 32bit

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a variable for every parameters and after call C function?
I experiment more or less similar issue and that came from a parameter send by pointer who was not directly declared.

```
Dim paramPortCom As Byte;
Dim paramMode As Byte;
Dim paramConfig As Byte;
Dim paramDbg As Byte;
Dim paramContext As String;
Dim resultFn As Byte;

' Set value into each variable
paramPortCom := 123;
...

' Call C function
resultFn := HR8_CONNECT(paramPortCom, ...);
```

Comment: Hello Camille, I tried also in this way but no effect ... thank you.